# Infer/allow extended type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to make example 1 work without the need to pass `<UserDomainEvent>` as in example 2?

Goal is to make usage simplier.

[Ts sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&jsx=0&isolatedModules=true#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgIgewLbAEsA7AUQDcBTIxAbwCgEFJgIDYFsiBGACmQMhUKUAFwIeFMTnzFyVCAEoEAXgB8CMtgIATBWM06ENBAF8GTCCzYciAJj4CIQ0QgA8AFQQUAHk6LaMaUJSSmpVCTF3JTUNLV19OKNTOjM6Oh8AB2woRBQ0DABVMGEg2VDEHz8ArDxguWojcwyAVxB+digKYG1OZABPBGbiqABJbTEiZtwQYRUELgBuFLSAehWEEYwIAAthCgRgBAB3YAGIbAR8AGt9nYFj7KuAGjo144Id7GbEHf2iCgo2gQ5wQGXywL6GX2YChsAIADM2Bh+DcEMQvN5gLgMsh9rYAPx0WCcSAIbbAfy4qBcOYRBBFEq1MryPSxQwxYxmUoheQAOk4vHJlOEXAUaWJRFJQu0VNsc1cDKg3PqEHCknpw2V5VZBiBHOSWr5nHs0tlCiAA)

```
abstract class DomainEvent {
  static on1(listener: (e: DomainEvent) => void): void { }
  static on2(listener: <T extends DomainEvent>(e: T) => void): void { }
}


export class UserDomainEvent extends DomainEvent {
  public readonly userId: number = 1;
}

// Usage

// Is there a way to make this work,
// without the need to pass type specifics like in example 2?
const handler = (e: UserDomainEvent): void => { }
DomainEvent.on1(handler) // error

const handler2 = <UserDomainEvent>(e: UserDomainEvent): void => { }
DomainEvent.on2(handler2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make the method `on` generic, but you don't have to explilcitly pass this generic type when calling it. the param type will be inferred

```
static on3<T extends DomainEvent>(listener: (e: T) => void): void { }
...
DomainEvent.on3(handler1)
```